# weird behaviour of date object

Tags: java, date

```
 SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("mm/dd/yyyy");
 Date date = dateFormat.parse("11/04/2011");
 System.out.println(date);
 System.out.println(dateFormat.format(date));

Tue Jan 04 00:11:00 IST 2011
11/04/2011
```

When output the date object it shows as january instead of november. But when format the same date object it shows november correctly.

By making MM/dd/yyyy it both shows the correct result. But Shouldnt the mm/dd/yyyy throws an Unparseable date exception if mm/dd/yyyy is fishy?

Comment: 'mm' minutes and 'MM' for months. Similarly 'ss` for seconds and `SS` for milli-seconds.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A common error: [`mm` is the pattern for *minutes*](http://download.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html). You want to use `MM` to parse/print the month. Use `MM/dd/yyyy` instead of `mm/dd/yyyy`.

Since you *parse* the value `11` into the minute-part of the date and then *print* the minute-part of the date in the first place, the result of `dateFormat.format(date)` *looks* correct.

Answer (score 4):

`mm/dd/yyyy` change it to `MM/dd/yyyy`

**Letter    Date or Time   Component    Presentation    Examples**

```
M   Month in year   Month   July; Jul; 07

m   Minute in hour  Number  30
```

**See**

- [API Doc](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.6/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html)

Answer (score 1):

Please note that Date is deprecated. You should use the Calendar class instead.

Comment: I´d go as far as proposing you use Joda-Time. It takes the suffering away from having to work with Dates in java.

Answer (score 1):

It is not fishy, capitalized M means Month in year and uncap m means Minute in hour
consult to this http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/index.html?java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html